# Laravel: Check file exists from a form validation request?

Tags: laravel

How to check if a file should be uploaded in a form validation request ?
This is what I have so far:

```
class UpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

     public function rules()
     {
         $rules = [
             'title' => 'required',
             'content' => 'required',
         ];

         if ($this->request->hasFile('image') && $this->request->file('image')->isValid()) {
             $rules['image'] = 'image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048|dimensions:min_width=100,min_height=100,max_width=1000,max_height=1000';
         }
 
         return $rules;
     }
}
```

but I get this error:

> Call to undefined method
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag::hasFile()

What can I do ?

Comment: I take it the image is optional i.e. a user can upload one but it isn't required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're trying to call `hasFile` on the underlying `request` property. Since `FormRequest` extends the normal Laravel `Request` class, you can simply call `$this->hasFile()` and `$this->file()`:

```
if ($this->hasFile('image') && $this->file('image')->isValid()) {
    $rules['image'] = 'image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048|dimensions:min_width=100,min_height=100,max_width=1000,max_height=1000';
}
```

That being said, it would make more sense to add [nullable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-nullable) to the validation rules if the image is optional since `image` will be checking to see if it's a valid file or not:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title'   => 'required',
        'content' => 'required',
        'images'  => [
            'nullable',
            'image',
            'mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg',
            'max:2048',
            'dimensions:min_width=100,min_height=100,max_width=1000,max_height=1000',
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: You're right, the second option is the best.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `request()` helper class to get request

your code should be like this

```php
class UpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

     public function rules()
     {
         $rules = [
             'title' => 'required',
             'content' => 'required',
         ];

         if (request()->hasFile('image') && request()->file('image')->isValid()) {
             $rules['image'] = 'image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048|dimensions:min_width=100,min_height=100,max_width=1000,max_height=1000';
         }
 
         return $rules;
     }
}
```

here `$this` refer to `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag` this class which doesn't have `hasFile()` function that's why your getting that error

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nullable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-nullable) validation rules. So all the validations will be applied only if the value is not null

```
 public function rules()
     {
         $rules['title'] = ['required'];
         $rules['content'] = ['required'];
         $rules['image'] = ['nullable', 'image','mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg','max:2048','dimensions:min_width=100,min_height=100,max_width=1000,max_height=1000'];
         return $rules;
     }
```